# Wordpress: One WP_Query / Multiple Post Types / Max Amount of Each Post Type

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I am developing the homepage of my new website, and I want to display a mixture of new posts from several POST TYPES. I've created shortcodes that each instigate individual `WP_Query` calls and return the appropriate data, but I feel it would be far more efficient to do this all in one `WP_Query` call on the homepage.

I am aware that I can call to multiple post types with:

```
WP_Query(array('post_type' => array('type1', 'type2', 'type3')))
```

And I am aware that I can set a limit on the amount of posts recieved back with

```
WP_Query(array('post_type' => array('type1', 'type2', 'type3'), 
'posts_per_page' => '30') )
```

But ideally I'd like a query that said... give me 4 of those, 3 of those and half a dozen of them!

Has anyone got any ideas?

**EDIT:**

After a little bit of feedback, it appears it may not be possible. If that's the case, am I worrying over nothing? I had thought there might be performance overhead with making multiple WP_Query requests.

Comment: So if I am correct, you want to call lets say 3 custom post types and limit the returned post of each post_type separately but with one wp_query?

Comment: Yes that's exactly right!

Comment: I cant think of any way you can do it with one wp_query, I'm pretty sure its not possible

Answer (score 0):

First of all, It would not be any overhead in doing 3 simple queries in a page. Wordpress itself perform a lot of queries per each pages.
There are many other bottlenecks that can cause performace loss and that you should take care about.

Under the hood WP_Query will basically produce a MySQL query, so it:

> "**SELECT** something **WHERE** some conditions are met **ORDER**ed BY some field and then **LIMIT**ed to N results".

*So if you can't give a particular order to your posts, you simply can't get what you want...*

Anyway, if you still want to do it with only one query, there are still a couple of chances.

1. **You can query by IDs**.
   You have to set manually your IDs in some way but you can get posts in the order you prefer:

```
WP_Query(['post__in' => [5,4,10,9], 'orderby' => 'post__in', 'posts_per_page' => 4]);
```

2. **Use a cross taxonomy or custom meta**
   You can attach a "common element" to your three custom post types (taxonomy or meta) and then query for it.
   You can achive this in many ways. I think that the simplier way is to use the built in "tag" taxonomy:

- Ensure that "post_tag" is assigned to your CPT.
  If you build your own CPT with `register_post_type()`, just add this:

```
'taxonomies' => array('post_tag')
```

OR add this to your `functions.php`

```
add_action( 'init', 'add_post_tag_to_my_custom_cpt', 10, 0 );
function 'add_post_tag_to_my_custom_cpt() {
    register_taxonomy_for_object_type( 'post_tag', 'type_1' );
    register_taxonomy_for_object_type( 'post_tag', 'type_2' );
    register_taxonomy_for_object_type( 'post_tag', 'type_3' );
};
```

- Assign a common "tag term", like "featured" to your favourite posts
- Use WP_Query with `tag` parameter

```
$posts = new WP_Query( array( 'tag' => 'featured' ) );
```